# Turn off the generation of externally referenced models in swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-3.0

Assume I have a yml file `example.yml` as given below:

```
ExampleResponse:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      StatusHeader:
        $ref: "#/definitions/StatusHeader"
      ResponseBody:
        $ref: "externaldefs.yaml#/Profile"
```

Now the model for `Profile`:

```
Profile:
  type: "object"
  required:
    - "ProfileKey"
    - "ProfileId"   
  properties:
    ProfileKey:
      type: "string"
    ProfileId:
      type: "string"
    PersonalInfo:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        FirstName:
         type: "string"
        LastName:
         type: "string"
```

What I want to do is that when I generate models using the `example.yml`, the class `Profile` should not be generated again and ExampleResponse class should get the correct import.

One way to do this is to give `systemProperties` and define all the other classes in `models` of `systemProperties` except the `Profile`. This works for small schemas and doesn't scale-up efficiently. I am looking for a better way to do this.

The example has been taken from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4070

Comment: Something like [`--import-mappings`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/#bringing-your-own-models)?

Comment: `--import-mappings` needs to be provided qualified path of the models you do not generate. When the external references are a lot, I will have to maybe make an input file and provide to --import-mappings. I am aware of this method. I am looking for something like the external reference is not generated all together.

Comment: [`-Dmodels=ModelNames`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/#selective-generation) also requires individual model names. Codegen doesn't differentiate between external and local $refs.